# MYSQL Big DB importing via MySQL Workbench is giving error , importing in wrong order

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a question , I have a BIG database to import via Mysql Work bench .   I am using MYSQL 5.7 , I am trying to import my database via workbanch ,but is giving error of raletad ID , it is not importing on right order .
It shoud import first -
* STATE TABLE 
* CITY TABLE ( with state_id )

but is importing city table before state table, so it is giving error , becose city table has state_id .

I have to import all the columns that comes first ( STATE TABLE ), after import those columns that comes after (CITY TABLE) .

IT is giving me a lot of problem this .Does this happened with some one ?
Does some one know what to do ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message? And why do you want to import this through the workbench and not through a CLI version that could directly access the dump (like through `SOURCE` as described on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html)?

Comment: When I did that, I had to make sure the dump tool would order the tables to respect foreign key constraints (put the foreing tables at the top of the dump).  You will have to reorder the dump, because MySQL Workbench imports top down. But you can turn off foreing key contraints during the import and turn them back on after.  Search for that, it might be simpler than reordering your tables in the dump.